# Firebase kotlin android studio app crashing on second activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I was following this youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hkyXuKTFYY) and the below happened. For him in the video, at 6:30, his app too crashed, but he solved it later in the video. For me, nothing seems to work.

Please HELP!

This is my logcat:

```
12-09 19:36:45.321 28337-28337/? E/Zygote: v2
12-09 19:36:45.331 28337-28337/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
12-09 19:36:47.831 28337-28337/konark.studios.ourtimetable E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: konark.studios.ourtimetable, PID: 28337
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{konark.studios.ourtimetable/konark.studios.ourtimetable.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3132)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:162)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:109)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:514)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
        at konark.studios.ourtimetable.RegisterActivity.<init>(RegisterActivity.kt:20)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The first Activity opens up as usual:## Heading ##
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8ALd.jpg)

When I press the Create Account button (at the bottom), it is supposed to move to the second activity. But unfortunately, it crashes.

Code of the second activity (that is crashing):

```kotlin
package konark.studios.ourtimetable

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Patterns
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var registerBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.RegisterButton)
    var usernamebox = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailbox)
    var passwordbox = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordbox)
    val intentLoginActivity = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)
        supportActionBar?.hide();
        auth = Firebase.auth

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener {
            signUpUser()
        }
    }

    private fun signUpUser() {

        if (usernamebox.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            usernamebox.error = "Please enter your email"
            usernamebox.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(usernamebox.text.toString()).matches()) {
            usernamebox.error = "Please enter a valid email"
            usernamebox.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        if (passwordbox.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
            passwordbox.error = "Please enter a password"
            passwordbox.requestFocus()
            return
        }

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usernamebox.text.toString(), passwordbox.text.toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        startActivity(Intent(intentLoginActivity))
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

This is the code of the first activity that is the home screen:

```
package konark.studios.ourtimetable

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.Button
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
        supportActionBar?.hide();
        auth = Firebase.auth

        var createAccountBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.AccountCreation)
        val intentAccountCreate = Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        createAccountBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Action","Register Button Clicked")
            startActivity(intentAccountCreate)
            finish()
        }
    }

    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var registerBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.RegisterButton)
> var usernamebox = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailbox)
> var passwordbox = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordbox)
> val intentLoginActivity = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
> ```

Move these function calls from property initializers to the `onCreate()` function.

At init phase, it's too early to use the `Activity` as a `Context` or have the activity window set up so you could call `findViewById()`. (Also before `setContentView()` you'll just get nulls back.)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that, but unfortunately, that didn't help. Also commenting out the signUpUser() function returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you Activity is declared inside your AndroidManifest file.
Then give a try :

```
createAccountBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val intentAccountCreate = Intent(context, RegisterActivity::class.java)
    Log.d("Action","Register Button Clicked")
    startActivity(intentAccountCreate)
    finish()
}
```

try to do it in the following way

Comment: @AbhinavPrabhakar try to comment once the part : window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN) , or by doing this.window.setFlags etc

Comment: :( Still the same

Comment: @AbhinavPrabhakar are you sure that your activity has been declared on your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yeah. A youtube video says the error could be due to old version of the dependencies, I upgraded them but still the same.